# Retrieving values from an extended hash in freemarker

Tags: hash, collections, sequence, freemarker

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
{
    "dataSet": [{
        "@etag": "2020-02-21T09:11:19.408         ",
        "text": "customer-old (ts001233)",
        "archived": true,
        "id": "932654d6-3f3b-452d-b256-66b9902a8952"
    }, {
        "@etag": "2021-12-21T21:12:13.648         ",
        "text": "customer (ts001234)",
        "archived": false,
        "id": "932654d6-3f3b-452d-b256-66b9902a8952"
    }, {
        "@etag": "2021-12-17T21:07:36.587         ",
        "text": "customer-test (ts001235)",
        "archived": false,
        "id": "85533cc2-320c-4d74-87e6-3233d26c8351"
    }],
    "templates": []
}
```

I'm trying to extract the value "customer (ts001234)", which I can do using the following code:

```
<#list dataSet as environments><#if environments.archived=false && !environments.text?contains('-test')>${environments.text}</#if></#list>
```

The problem is that this code relies on filtering a text value (-test) which I'd rather not use since the text values may vary. Instead, I want to retrieve the **first** non archived environment.

I tried using ?first :

```
<#list dataSet as environments><#if environments.archived=false && !environments.text?contains('-test')>${environments?first.text}</#if></#list>
```

But that leads to an error:

```
For "?first" left-hand operand: Expected a sequence or collection, but this has evaluated to an extended_hash (LinkedHashMap wrapped into f.t.DefaultMapAdapter):
==> environments  [in nameless template at line 1, column 119]
```

Can someone please give me some pointers on how to retrieve this value without filtering the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `environments` corresponds to `[{"@etag": ...}, ...]` in your example, what you tried to do, I guess, is this:

```
<#assign firstUnarchived = environments?filter(it -> !it.archived)[0]>
```

This will fail if you have no unarchived entry though. So probably you want just assign `environments?filter(it -> !it.archived)` to a variable (without the `[0]`), let's say `unarchivedEnvs`, and then check if `unarchivedEnvs?size != 0`, etc.

In case you are using a FreeMarker version older than 2.3.29, where you will have to use `#list` for this, when you find the first match with `#if`, you can exit the loop with `<#break>`.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of filtering the sequence. 

I made it work with: 
<#assign firstUnarchivedEnvironment= dataSet?filter(it -> !it.archived)[0]>
(...) ${firstUnarchivedEnvironment.text}